# How to forward special field from class to Grid in Vaadin?

Tags: java, list, interface, polymorphism, vaadin

I have got a class StockDayRating:

```
public class StockDayRating {
    private String close;
    public String getClose() {
        return close;
    }
}
```

And class Stock:

```
public class Stock {
    private String name;
    private List<StockDayRating> stockDayRating;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<StockDayRating> getStockDayRating() {
        return stockDayRating;
    }
}
```

And now I would like to add "Stock::getStockDayRating" to Grid in Vaadin (so far everything work):

```
grid.addColumn(Stock::getStockDayRating).setCaption("Value");
```

The problem is when I want to add "Stock::getStockDayRating::getClose" to Grid in Vaadin, not the whole list but only special field "close".
Something like this (below) doesn't work and I don't know how to solve it:

```
grid.addColumn(Stock::getStockDayRating::getClose).setCaption("Value");
```

The Grid method from Vaadin looks like:

```
public <V> Grid.Column<T, V> addColumn(ValueProvider<T, V> valueProvider) {
        return this.addColumn((ValueProvider)valueProvider, (AbstractRenderer)(new TextRenderer()));
    }
```

The output error is:

```
method reference not expected here
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grid.addColumn(stock-> stock.getStockDayRating().stream()
                            .map(StockDayRating::getClose)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

(because `Stock::getStockDayRating::getClose` is invalid syntax).

#### Why?

The method `addColumn` in `Grid` receives a parameter of type `ValueProvider<T,V>`

```
addColumn(ValueProvider<T,V> valueProvider)
```

where `ValueProvider<T,V>` is a [functional interface](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/) with a method `V  apply(T source)`.

`Stock::getStockDayRating` is a reference to the method `getStockDayRating` in class `Stock` that returns `List<StockDayRating>`. Then, `Stock::getStockDayRating` is compatible with `ValueProvider<Stock,List<StockDayRating>>` and `addColumn(Stock::getStockDayRating)` boils down to:

```
grid.addColumn(new ValueProvider<Stock,List<StockDayRating>>(){
   List<StockDayRating> apply(Stock stock) {
      return stock.getStockDayRating();
   }
});
```

Now, suppose that you want to display the *size* of the list (i.e. `stock.getStockDayRating().size()`). You cannot write it as a method reference, since there are *two* method calls involved, so you need to use a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) `stock->stock.getStockDayRating().size()` which is compatible with `ValueProvider<Stock,Integer>`

With Java 7 syntax (which is also valid in Java 8, albeit more verbose), that can be written as:

```
grid.addColumn(new ValueProvider<Stock,Integer>(){
   Integer apply(Stock stock) {
      return stock.getStockDayRating().size();
   }
});
```

> The problem is when I want to add (...) not the whole list but only special field "close". Something like below works but it is only direct into 0 index element but I would like for all elements `grid.addColumn(stock->stock.getStockDayRating().get(0).getC‌​lose());`

`stock.getStockDayRating()` returns a list of `StockDayRating`, 
and suppose that `StockDayRating.getClose()` returns `BigDecimal`.
You want to convert a `List<StockDayRating>` into a `List<BigDecimal>` of close prices.

For that, you can use the stream operation [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) the transformed stream into a `List`:

```
stock-> stock.getStockDayRating().stream()
             .map(StockDayRating::getClose)
             .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

1. `map` returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of a stream.
2. `collect` performs a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) on the elements of this stream using a `Collector`.
3. The method [`toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) (from `java.util.stream.Collectors`) returns a `Collector` that accumulates the input elements into a new `List`.

Comment: Something like this: **'grid.addColumn(stock->stock.getStockDayRating());'** compile, but it is not what I want. Something like this **'grid.addColumn(stock->stock.getStockDayRating().getClose())‌​;'** doesn't compile. Error **'cannot find symbol method getClose()'**. Something like below works but it is only direct into 0 index element but I would like for all elements **'grid.addColumn(stock->stock.getStockDayRating().get(0).getClose());'**.

Comment: My fault, at some point I missed the fact that `getStockDayRating` returns a `List`